# Is T&L technology obsolete?

Tags: opengl, directx, gpu

I search some information about how GPU works. From different sources i found out that T&L (Transform and Lighting) technology used for hardware acceleration. For example, it calculates polygon lighting. But as I know, today the developers are using programmable graphic pipeline, and create lighting by shaders.
So, what is T&L today used for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The classic 'Transform & Lighting' fixed-function hardware along with the "Texture blend cascade" fixed-function hardware is generally considered obsolete. Instead, the "T&L" phase has been replaced with Vertex Shaders, and the "Texture blend cascade" has been replace with Pixel Shaders.

For older legacy APIs that have a 'fixed-function' mode (Direct3D 9, OpenGL 1.x), most modern cards actually emulate the original behavior with programmable shaders.

> There's an example for Direct3D 11 that emulates most (but not all) of the classic Direct3D 9 fixed-function modes if want to take a look at it on [GitHub](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-sdk-samples/blob/master/FixedFuncEMUFX11/FixedFuncEMU.fx).

Generally speaking, you are better off using a set of shaders that implements the features you actually use rather than a bunch of stuff you don't.